# Cambios de tipo de variable(Java)

Tags: java

Buenas. Trabajo con NetBeans y Java 8. Tengo un problemita con respecto a las variables de java, más concretamente a la hora de cambiar de tipo. Por ejemplo, cuando defino un *int* y lo quiero cambiar a *double*, no funciona aun usando, 

`int a = 3;
double b = (double) a;`

Además, he probado el código en el intérprete de SoloLearn y ha funcionado, lo que me hace preguntar. Es obsoleto alguno de los dos intérpretes?

Comment: Y que error te lanza que no te fumciona?

Comment: No deberías tener errores de compilación, podrías agregarlo? Ademas, no es necesario el cast, puedes asignar double b = a y obtendras 3.0

Comment: Marcos, lo que has escrito era lo que yo pensaba, pero igualmente no me ha dejado compilar aunque agregue

Comment: @Dacoso, intentaré escribirlo aquí cuanto antes, aunque creo que hoy no podrá ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esta obsoleto o no, no obstante te dejo algunas opciones que encontre:

```
Opcion 1: (haciendo un cast)
int i;
Math.sqrt((double)i)

Opcion 2: (multiplicando por 1.0)
int i; 
double r; 
r = i*1.0;

Opcion 3: (un poco lo que hiciste tu, parecido)
int entero;
double coma;

coma=(double)entero/100;
```

Prueba alguna de esas formas a ver si te funciona y me dices si se soluciono.

Comment: El método Math.sqrt() no es para cambiar de tipo, este método te devuelve la raíz cuadrada de un número. Su resultado si que es de tipo double.

Comment: Gracias por la info, tal vez de esa forma pueda asignarselo a un double y luego volver a hacer el cuadrado XD aunque seguro que hay opciones menos liantes

Comment: por que en la opcion 3 lo divide por 100?

Comment: ni idea, pero esa operacion de dividir por 100 para pasarlo a double no está bien. Si eso funciona también tiene que funcionar lo que ha puesto @Vybr que ha dicho que no le va